# PyAudio -- How to capture microphone and system sounds in a single stream?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, portaudio, recorder

i'm trying to build an app with pyaudio that records speaker and microphone sound but i just don't know how to record them both.I tried enabling stereo mixer but it didn't work out because i could only listen the sound from the speakers.
This code that i'm using records audio from the default microphone in a background thread using pyaudio:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp/tmp.wav"

class recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False
        self.process = None
        self.filename = "ScreenCapture.mpg"
    def record(self,filename):
        try:
            if self.process.is_alive():
                self.going = False
        except AttributeError:
            print("test")
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename
    def _record(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                        channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        print("* recording")

        frames = []

        self.going = True

        while self.going:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)

        print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False
```

I'm using Windows and I can also use other library, not only PyAudio. I just need to get this work.

Edit : I found this code to record the output from speaker but i couldn't make it work in my application:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

SPEAKERS = p.,get_default_output_device_info()["hostApi"] 
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                input_host_api_specific_stream_info=SPEAKERS,
                as_loopback=True) 

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

**UPDATE** :
I could record both my speaker and my microphone with this:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np


CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 2
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp.wav"


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


#stream using as_loopback to get sound from OS
stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = 2,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    input_device_index=2,
    as_loopback=True)

##stream using my Microphone's input device
stream2 = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = 1,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    input_device_index=1)
    #as_loopback=False)


frames = []
frames2 = []


for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
    frames2.append(data2)


#frames = as_loopback sound data (Speakers)
frames= b''.join(frames);

#frames2 = sound data of Microphone
frames2= b''.join(frames2);

#decoding Speaker data
Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')

#decoding the microphone data
Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

#converting Speaker data into a Numpy vector (making life easier when picking up audio channels)
Sdecoded= np.array(Sdecoded, dtype='int16') 

#getting the data on the right side
direito=Sdecoded[1::2]

#getting the data on the left side
esquerdo=Sdecoded[::2]

#mixing everything to mono = add right side + left side + Microphone decoded data that is already mono
mix=(direito+esquerdo+Mdecoded)

#ensuring no value goes beyond the limits of short int
signal=np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

#encode the data again
encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh"%(len(signal)), *list(signal))


#stop all streams and terminate pyaudio
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
stream2.stop_stream()
stream2.close()
p.terminate()


#recording mixed audio in mono 
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes((encodecoded))
wf.close()
```

But when i try to mix with my code it doesn't work.What is going on?I think i'm almost solving it

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp/tmp.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


class recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False
        self.process = None
        self.filename = "ScreenCapture.mpg"
    def record(self,filename):
        try:
            if self.process.is_alive():
                self.going = False
        except AttributeError:
                print("test")
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename
    def _record(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        #stream using as_loopback to get sound from OS
        stream = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=2,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=2,
            as_loopback=True)
        ##stream using my Microphone's input device
        stream2 = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=1,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=1)
        # as_loopback=False)
        #print("* recording")

        frames = []
        frames2= []

        self.going = True

        while self.going:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)
            frames2.append(data2)
        # frames = as_loopback sound data (Speakers)
        frames = b''.join(frames);

        # frames2 = sound data of Microphone
        frames2 = b''.join(frames2);

        # decoding Speaker data
        Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')

        # decoding the microphone data
        Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

        # converting Speaker data into a Numpy vector (making life easier when picking up audio channels)
        Sdecoded = np.array(Sdecoded, dtype='int16')

        # getting the data on the right side
        direito = Sdecoded[1::2]

        # getting the data on the left side
        esquerdo = Sdecoded[::2]

        # mixing everything to mono = add right side + left side + Microphone decoded data that is already mono

        mix = (direito + esquerdo + Mdecoded)

        # ensuring no value goes beyond the limits of short int

        signal = np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

        # encode the data again
        encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh" % (len(signal)), *list(signal))

       # print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        stream2.stop_stream()
        stream2.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(encodecoded)
        wf.close()


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False
```

I made the code very clean and commented each part so you understand what is going on.I made a for loop in the beginning for Pyaudio show me what are the interfaces I have in my OS:

```
0 Mapeador de som da Microsoft - Input
1 Microfone (Realtek(R) Audio)
2 Mixagem estéreo (Realtek(R) Aud
3 Mapeador de som da Microsoft - Output
4 Alto-falantes (Realtek(R) Audio
5 Alto-falantes (Realtek(R) Audio)
6 Microfone (Realtek(R) Audio)
7 Mixagem estéreo (Realtek(R) Audio)
8 Speakers 1 (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
9 Speakers 2 (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
10 Alto-falante (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
11 Microfone (Realtek HD Audio Mic input)
12 Mixagem estéreo (Realtek HD Audio Stereo input)
```

Comment: Share the code that you are using for recording from the "Stereo Mix"

Comment: It's the same code.I just changed the default microphone to stereo mix and somehow i could hear the sound from the speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 separate threads to record from 2 different devices ( providing separate device Index) into separate Wav files.

Then Mix these 2 files Using the [pydub](http://pydub.com/) library

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

speakersound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/speaker.wav")
micsound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/mic.wav")

mixsound = speakersound.overlay(micsound)

mixsound.export("/path/mixsound.wav", format='wav')
```

Comment: How can i separate 2 threads to record from 2 different devices?Thanks for your help and time.I wasn't expecting  anyone to show up.

Comment: Thank you for deleting the duplicate queries. first try running 2 separate py script 1. Stereo Mix  2. microphone. Run these 2 script in separate terminal. Share the result.

Comment: if you want people to give more attention to your question, start a bounty, more people will be ready to answer your question.

Comment: HI @mail2subhajit
Could please see my updated code?I think i'm almost solving it.Thanks very much for you help and sorry again for the duplicated queries.

Comment: I used numpy to decoded faster.i 
In this code I use it to convert lists to vectors, also used the clip function that works as a limiter in the audio, when you mix something you just add the vectors, in doing so you will inevitably extrapolate the minimum value of short int so we need to force extrapolated data to be within range with the clip function.After the capture ends I started the whole process of audio decoding, converting audio from stereo to mono, clipping the audio, and finally recording everything in mono at 44100Hz in a .wav file.But it doens't work inside my project.

Comment: I hope it makes sense

Comment: If you think it is very complex i can pay you 100 dollars to help me finish.I just need to do that and it's over.

Comment: Sure Gabriel I will revert back the down vote, Can You Share me the recorded file from the Mic and the speaker in separate file (.wav file) .

Comment: I already solved it.If you want we can hire you as our consultant for further implementations.

Comment: I wanted to make the user enter some kind of license also before using the application.I don't know if it is possible with python.

Comment: Good  News that you are able to solve the problem yourself .. thank you for the kind words.

Comment: Can you give me more details of the license part ( serial key or login wise ), then I can give you some suggestions.

Comment: It would be a serial key.When you enter this license key, the software must allow you to use the software.After the user enters the license key, my software should remember that he entered the valid key. (Because next time, he won't have to open the license dialog)

Comment: Read : https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/01c41az6bx/license-key-validation-encryption-decryption

Comment: You can encrypt and store the license key in separate file or put it in the python code, license key & key provided by the user ( Private and Public Key ). you can write a function to validate this key at the start of the program, by checking the private and public key.  Read more about the cryptography  : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography_with_python/cryptography_with_python_quick_guide.htm

Comment: if more help is required, please post this question separately to this forum.

Comment: Interesting.I will take a look at this.Thanks again.